# Score keyword terms query on nested fields in elastichsearch 6.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of keywords (skills in my example) and I would like to retrieve documents which match most of them. The documents should be sorted by how many of the keywords they match. The field i am searching into (`skills`) is of `nested` type. The index has the following mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "profiles": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "skills": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "level": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried both a terms query on the keyword field like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "skills.name": [
            "python",
            "java"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a boolean query

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "skills.name": [
                    "java"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "skills.name": [
                    "r"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

For both queries the maximum score of the returned documents is 1. Thus both return documents that have ANY of the skills, but do not sort them such those with both skills are on top. The issues seems to be that `skills` is a `nested` field.

Comment: The second query should score documents with both `java` and `r` better than the first query. Can you share the scores you're getting for the top documents using the second query?

Comment: The maximum score I get for the second query is 1. However if I would search on different fields (e.g. skills and titles) then the should query works as expected.

Comment: Can you share your mapping and the version of ES you're running?

Comment: It is a nested field. I checked now on a non-nested field and the `should` query works as expected. My bad, I wanted to simplify the setup but it seems the nested type is the issue. I will update the question and provide the mapping.

Comment: It's pretty different if the field is nested, indeed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The second query works if each element of `should` is a nested query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "skills",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "skills.name": [
                  "java"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "skills",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "skills.name": [
                  "r"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```